# How can I pack tkinter buttons vertically?

Tags: python, tkinter

How I can put the following buttons in vertical instead of horizontal? because I want to put these buttons in left vertically and picture in right? "in python language"

```
    self.myParent = parent   
    self.myContainer1 = Frame(parent)
    self.myContainer1.pack()

    self.button1 = Button(self.myContainer1, command=self.button1Click)
    self.button1.configure(text="Generate The Fraud Detection File", background= "grey")
    self.button1.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.button1.focus_force()         


    self.button3 = Button(self.myContainer1, command=self.button2Click) 
    self.button3.configure(text="       Cancel       ", background="grey")     
    self.button3.pack(side=RIGHT)


    self.button3 = Button(self.myContainer1, command=self.button2Click) 
    self.button3.configure(text="       Edit        ", background="grey")     



    self.button2 = Button(self.myContainer1, command=self.button3Click) 
    self.button2.configure(text="Disply The File of Fraud Detection", background="grey")     
    self.button2.pack(side=RIGHT)

    self.button4 = Button(self.myContainer1, command=self.button4Click) 
    self.button4.configure(text="Display The Monthly Chart", background="grey")     
    self.button4.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

Comment: What gui framework are you using?

Comment: how bout `pack(side=BOTTOM)` for all your buttons (maybe top for first one?)

Answer (score 3):

Create two frames. Pack one on the left for the buttons, one on the right for everything else. Then, add the buttons to the left frame and pack them with `side="top"` or `side="bottom"`.

Don't be afraid to use additional frames to block out your GUI into sections. It's much easier to lay out GUIs doing that, rather than trying to get everything lined up inside a single window using a single geometry manager.